# bash script split if argument set

Tags: bash, unix, if-statement, arguments, command-line-arguments

Here is some pseudo-code for what I'm trying to achieve with a bash program.

This program will be called with either:

`filesplit -u` OR `filesplit --update`

`filesplit`

```
 if -u (or --update) is set:

   echo "Update"

 else:

   echo "No Update
```

How can this split be achieved in a bash script?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Script parameters in Bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003370/script-parameters-in-bash)

Answer (score 2):

You can check for both values using `@(val1|val2)` syntax inside `[[...]]`:

```
filesplit() {
    [[ "${1?needs an argument}" == -@(u|-update) ]] && echo "Update" || echo "No Update"
}
```

**Testing:**

```
filesplit -b
No Update
filesplit -u
Update
filesplit --update
Update
filesplit --update1
No Update
filesplit
-bash: 1: needs an argument
```

Comment: `extglob` is only needed for using extended patterns when doing filename generation. Extended patterns are assumed inside `[[...]]`.

Answer (score 2):

Just use logical or `||` in a `[[ ... ]]` condition:

```
if [[ $1 == -u || $1 == --update ]] ; then
    echo Update
else
    echo No Update
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
case "$1" in
  -u|--update)
      echo update
      ;;
  *)
      echo no update
      ;;
esac
```