# How to pass an argument to shell script

Tags: linux, bash, unix, input

I'm kinda new in bash, the thing is I need to run several set of data in a program, I make a bash script that allow me to do it automatically... the problem is when the program start it needs some inputs and I don't know how to give it inside the bash?
 I execute the program:

```
$./bin/mg5_aMC
```

The program opens and I need to pass some input to run (mg5> is the enviroment of the program):

```
mg5>launch file.lhe
```

the program runs, and ask for something:

```
mg5> 1
```

and then again, ask for something and i need to press enter..

```
mg5> (enter)
```

PD.: I edited the question because I suppose didn't express myself very well..

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood from your question, you either want 1) to pass parameters when calling your Bash script, or 2) some sort of interactive shell within your script.

For #1, passing parameters to a Bash script, these links may be helpful:

- [Script parameters in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003370/script-parameters-in-bash)
- [Bash scripting Tutorial](http://linuxconfig.org/bash-scripting-tutorial)

Basically, you need to use the following call for your script:

```
./bin/mg5_aMC launch xxx.lhe 1
```

And within your script, you refer to each argument using a numbered variable:

```
action=$1
file=$2
n=$3
```

As for #2, consult the following links/examples:

- [How do I prompt for input in a Linux shell script?](http://How%20do%20I%20prompt%20for%20input%20in%20a%20Linux%20shell%20script?)
- [Bash Scripting Tutorial - 3. User Input](http://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-input.php)

There are quite a few resources online and on this site that will provide you more example and explanations.

Answer (score 0):

If the program can get its input as arguments passed from the command line, then you can write the parameters in a file, call it e.g. `params`, then do

```
./bin/mg5_aMC $(<params)
```

Comment: This will also create other problems: impossible to give arguments with spaces or glob characters…

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you rather want to catch user's input, than simply pass args to executed script. `read` command allows you to catch user's input. Did it answers your question?