# How to get arguments from console in java when using a bash file?

Tags: java, bash

I have a java project that I launch using a bash file :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

java -classpath logger/bin:banking/bin:testframework/bin test.RunTest
```

I launch my bash in my terminal (in ubuntu) :

```
firefrost@firefrost-PC:~/ProjetPOO3A$ bash test.sh banking.Account
```

In my main, I try to get arguments as :

```
public class RunTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(args.length);
    for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
    {
...
```

The problem is that args.length is 0 when it should be 1 because I passed the argument "banking.Account" in my console.

If I put the argument in the bash file :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

java -classpath logger/bin:banking/bin:testframework/bin test.RunTest banking.Account
```

my main recognize the argument and the System.out.println outputs 1.

Why is the argument in the console not taken into account?

Comment: You have to parse the argument in the bash file then pass it to the java commandline

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003370/script-parameters-in-bash

Comment: thanks, I didn't get them in my search for answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem in Java code. Your parameters are not propagated to `java` command in shell script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
java -classpath logger/bin:banking/bin:testframework/bin test.RunTest "$@"
```

The `$@` variable contains all parameters passed to shell script.

Answer (score 1):

Command line arguments to a bash script can be accessed with `$1`, `$2`, *etc*.  Here's a [fuller explanation](https://www.lifewire.com/pass-arguments-to-bash-script-2200571).

Try updating your script as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

java -classpath logger/bin:banking/bin:testframework/bin test.RunTest $1
```

Comment: Thanks! does $@ gets all arguments I pass?

Comment: That's a good question.  The answer is to use `$@`.  Someone else has (thoughtfully) already covered that option.  It's also covered in the link I posted.

Answer (score 1):

You forget to process the argument in the bash file.

You can access them by using $1, $2, $3, $... variables.

For example writing `./my.sh test test2` $1 will contain test and $2 test2

So change your script to

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
java -classpath logger/bin:banking/bin:testframework/bin test.RunTest $1
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `"$@"` to pass the arguments to the program:

```
#!/bin/bash

java -classpath logger/bin:banking/bin:testframework/bin test.RunTest "$@"
```

Don't forget the quotes around `$@` so bash will "protect" each argument:

> *@*
>
> Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the
>   expansion occurs within double quotes, each parameter expands to a
>   separate word. That is, "$@" is equivalent to "$1" "$2" ... If the
>   double-quoted expansion occurs within a word, the expansion of the
>   first parameter is joined with the beginning part of the original
>   word, and the expansion of the last parameter is joined with the last
>   part of the original word. When there are no positional parameters,
>   "$@" and $@ expand to nothing (i.e., they are removed).

See [bash man](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).