# Check the validity of variable number of positional parameters provided as input to a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

For compiling a set of applications for multiple platforms, there are certain build exports which need to be set.

The sample command is as under:

`source exports_file.sh <plaforms> <feature1> <feature2> <feature3>`

Here the positional parameter `<platform>` is mandatory whereas the other parameters such as `<feature1>, <feature2>, <feature3>` are optional. These have to be enabled only if the corresponding feature is needed in the build.

The set of valid command line options are:

`source exports_file.sh <plaforms> <feature1> <feature2> <feature3>
source exports_file.sh <plaforms> <feature1> <feature2>
source exports_file.sh <plaforms> <feature1>
source exports_file.sh <plaforms>`

Important thing to note is that the script should return an error if:

1) `<platform>` input param is not provided by the user.

2) Value of `<platform>` input param is not present in the list i.e. it is other than 1234, 1235 or 1236.

3) Any other feature apart from `<feature1>, <feature2>, <feature3>` are provided as input.

I have written a script which works fine but I'm not sure if its checking the validity of all the input parameters correctly.

```
   $> cat exports_file.sh


    if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then

    platform=$1

    # Common exports
    unset PLATFORM
    unset ENABLE_FEATURE_1
    unset ENABLE_FEATURE_2
    unset ENABLE_FEATURE_3

    echo "INFO: Setting common exports for $platform"
    if [ $platform == "1234" ]
    then
        export PLATFORM=91234

    elif [ $platform == "1235" ]
    then
        export PLATFORM=91235

    elif [ $platform == "1236" ]
    then
        export PLATFORM=91236

    else
        echo "ERROR: Exports are not defined for $platform."
        exit 1
    fi

    # Check for feature based exports <feature1> <feature2> <feature3>
    for var in "$@"
    do
        if [ $var == "arg2" ]
        then
            export ENABLE_FEATURE_1=Y

        elif [ $var == "arg3" ]
        then
            export ENABLE_FEATURE_2=Y

        elif [ $var == "arg4" ]
        then
            export ENABLE_FEATURE_3=Y
        else
            echo "ERROR: unrecognised argument '$var'";
            exit 1
        fi
    done
else
    echo "ERROR: No inputs parameters provided to the scripts."
    echo "Usage: source exports_file.sh <plaforms> <feature1> <feature2> <feature3>"
fi`
```

Is there a better way to write this script. Most important thing is to ensure the validity of all the input parameters.

Comment: For starters test your script here https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Older discussion: [Script parameters in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003370/script-parameters-in-bash) | [How do I parse command line arguments in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse command line arguments in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash)

Comment: Thanks @Digvijay. The links provided by you are really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `case` statement will simplify your code. First, though, exit as soon as possible when you find an error, so that the rest of you code doesn't need to be indented.

```
if [ $# = 0 ]; then
    echo "ERROR: No inputs parameters provided to the scripts." >&2
    echo "Usage: source exports_file.sh <plaforms> <feature1> <feature2> <feature3>" >&2
    exit 1
fi

platform=$1
shift

echo "INFO: Setting common exports for $platform" >&2
case $platform in 
    1234|1235|1236) export PLATFORM=9$platform ;;
    *) echo "ERROR: Exports are not defined for $platform" >&2
       exit 1 ;;
esac


# Check for feature based exports <feature1> <feature2> <feature3>
for var in "$@"
do
    case $var in
      arg2) export ENABLE_FEATURE_1=Y ;;
      arg3) export ENABLE_FEATURE_2=Y ;;
      arg4) export ENABLE_FEATURE_3=Y ;;
      *) echo "ERROR: unrecognized argument '$var'" >&2
         exit 1;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: Thanks @chepner, Thanks for your solution. I like your approach to the problem and its a good starting point for me. One thing i missed to mention is that each and every export is different, so I cannot generalize as you have done `export PLATFORM=9$platform`. Also for every case there are more than one exports. But as i said your solution is a good starting point for me. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks chepner, i was able to solve my problem. I have accepted your answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
  if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then

    platform=$1

    # Common exports
    unset PLATFORM
    unset ENABLE_FEATURE_1
    unset ENABLE_FEATURE_2
    unset ENABLE_FEATURE_3
    echo  input parameter: $@

    echo "INFO: Setting common exports for $platform"
    if [ $platform == "1234" ]
    then
        export PLATFORM=91234
        export ENABLE_FEATURE_1=Y
        # Result
        echo $PLATFORM
        echo $ENABLE_FEATURE_1

    elif [ $platform == "1235" ]
    then
        export PLATFORM=91235
        export ENABLE_FEATURE_2=Y
        # Result
        echo $PLATFORM
        echo $ENABLE_FEATURE_2

    elif [ $platform == "1236" ]
    then
        export PLATFORM=91236
        export ENABLE_FEATURE_3=Y
        # Result
        echo $PLATFORM
        echo $ENABLE_FEATURE_3

    else
       echo "ERROR: Exports are not defined for $platform."
        exit 1
    fi
    fi

    # Check for feature based exports <feature1> <feature2> <feature3>
    #for var in "$@"
    #do
        #if [ $var == "arg2" ]
        #then
            #export ENABLE_FEATURE_1=Y

        #elif [ $var == "arg3" ]
        #then
            #export ENABLE_FEATURE_2=Y

        #elif [ $var == "arg4" ]
        #then
            #export ENABLE_FEATURE_3=Y
        #else
            #echo "ERROR: unrecognised argument '$var'";
            #exit 1
        #fi
    #done
#else
   #echo "ERROR: No inputs parameters provided to the scripts."
    #echo "Usage: source exports_file.sh <plaforms> <feature1> <feature2> <feature3>"
#fi
```